# can't update-initramfs generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64 error

Tags: linux, upgrade

Hi today I did a upgrade in my debian after of this.  have a problem really I look a solution for this problem and I don't find anything.[image: error here]

```
Configurando linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre «/etc/udev/udev.conf»: No existe el fichero o el directorio
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64.postinst line 634.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**NEW PROBLEM WITH THE COMAND:**

> sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall udev

**HAVE THIS:**

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Configurando udev (215-17+deb8u3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: fopen(/etc/insserv.conf): No such file or directory
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service udev
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete udev (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.120) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 udev
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the text from the console — BTW do you know you can use the central mouse button to paste text from a TTY in a file opened in an editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can try restoring the default `udev.conf`.  After

```
mv /etc/udev/udev.conf /etc/udev/udev.conf.broken
```

(in case the file actually exists but is unreadable for some other reason e.g. a symlink to nowhere)

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall udev
```

(Apparently for some packages it's necessary to prefix with UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1 instead, joy.  But I don't think the udev package uses ucf).

---

However if this is more than an accident affecting the one file, you're probably best making backup copies of anything you want to keep and re-installing the OS as a whole.

You don't know what caused it; I can't think of anything obvious.  If you try fixing files one at a time, you're likely to miss something that will mysteriously break later on.

Unfortunately there isn't a simple way to reinstall all packages inside a running system.  E.g. `aptitude reinstall ?installed` - it fails with something like `Couldn't configure perl-base, probably a dependency cycle`.

Comment: yeah now I have other problem i shown in the question

Comment: give up (on this debian install, you can always make a new one :P).  Edited answer.